# React jsx ternary operator multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

I need to return multiple values in jsx from ternary operator, in this case 2, one is string from object, and second is just string. I tried this, but this doesn't work.

```
export const alignMap = {
  left: 'mr-auto',
  center: 'mx-auto',
  right: 'ml-auto',
};

<div className={`${condtion ? (alignMap.left, 'recommended-dish-price') : (alignMap.right, 'dish-price')}`}>{price}</div>
```

Is there any way to return multiple values from ternary operator like this?

Comment: Concatenate the strings, e.g., `\`${alignMap.left} recommended-dish-price\``

Comment: You can't, however if both are string values you could combine them first.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
export const alignMap = {
  left: 'mr-auto',
  center: 'mx-auto',
  right: 'ml-auto',
};

<div className={`${condtion ?  (alignMap.left + ' recommended-dish-price') : (alignMap.right + ' dish-price')}`}>{price}</div>
```

as `,` separated values are will always return you the value after the `,`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate things like that,
you can simply replace the code above with this:

```
<div className={`${condtion ? 'mr-auto recommended-dish-price' : 'ml-auto dish-price'}`}>{price}</div>
```

Also I have to mention that you are making a typo in word "condtion" . I recommend you to correct the spelling.